# glBufferData fails silently with overly large sizes

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia

i just noticed, that glBufferData fails silently when i try to call it with size: 1085859108 and data: NULL.

Following calls to glBufferSubData fail with a OUT_OF_MEMORY 'Exception'. This is on Windows XP 32bit, NVIDIA Gforce 9500 GT (1024MB) and 195.62 Drivers.

Is there any way to determinate if a buffer was created sucessfully? (Something like a proxy texture for example?)

kind regards,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that it's really silent. I'd guess that `glGetError` would return `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` after that attempt.

Comment: nope ... in the end it was my fault ... i don't remember what it was but i did something wrong there
(should worry cause i forget things i did half an hour before ... ;) )